# Hiding column's in YII CGridView

Tags: php, html, yii

I have a table with more than 5 columns , i want to hide some columns so that those column's are shown only if some row is selected or its expanded .

Am using yiiframework's CGridView , so how can i do this in that ?

Any help is appreciable ..

I want a feature like this, so that on expanding a particular record i can see the hidden column values

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way is :

```
 'columns'=>array(
        array(
          'name'=>'columnName',
          'visible'=>false
            ),
         )
```

So you need to manipulate visibility attributes dynamically :

```
 'visible'=>$this->checkVisible() //custom function
```

sth like this depending on your requirement

## **Edit** (using ajax +jquery)

example :**views/user/admin.php**

```
.....
.....
<?php
$toggleUDetails = <<<JS
 $('a.toggle').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(this.href.split('#')[1]=='loaded') return $(this).closest("tr").next('tr.toggle').toggle();

    trow=$(this).closest("tr");

   var ajaxOpts={type:"POST", url:this.href ,dataType:'json',success:function(data){
            $(trow).after(data.row);
      }
    };

   this.href=this.href+'#loaded';

   $.ajax(ajaxOpts);

  });
JS;
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('toggleUD', $toggleUDetails, CClientScript::POS_READY); 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
     array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
         'header'=>'Toggle Details',
          'template'=>'{toggle}',
            'buttons'=>array(
              'toggle'=>array(
                        'label'=>'Details',                        
                             'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/expand.png',  
                             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("user/getExtra", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                             'options'=>array('class'=>'toggle',

                                      ),
                               ),
                        ),
          ),

        'id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

## **User Controller**

```
public function actionGetExtra($id){
        $model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
        echo json_encode(array('row'=> '<tr class="toggle"><td   colspan="6">'. $model->username.'</td></tr>'));

  }
```

**Enable access rights:**

```
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','getExtra'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
```

that much I can do you for . Remember to change the Java script function to toggle the image icon 
I have not done that

Comment: does that requires ajax request to server or you want to do on client side ? In checkVisbile() function put you logic  when to make the field  visible. When you say "select or toggle " I assume that it involves ajax request

Comment: No i want to hide it within the document .. ( no ajax )

Comment: Hiding grid column is possible through ajax ,which will not STICK to-gather if you make an ajax request. E.g if you hide column(s) through javascript but when you refresh the Grid by search/selection/page navigation the hidden column will again visible .So my understanding is that you should handle the visibility of grid column at server-side

Comment: the exact issue has already been addressed here , plz follow the forum thread : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29387-2-rows-per-item-in-cgridview/

Comment: this is fine , but for doing this i need to treat the extra columns as another tuple, how can i do this as all the columns in a row are of the same model

Comment: check my edits using ajax and jquery .The only extra column will be ajax based toggle image link as you have show . On the first click it will get the details through ajax , next time it will just toggle the extra row added

Comment: `$('a.toggle').live('click',function(e){` instead of     `$('a.toggle').click(function(e){` to support your custom function on ajax page navigation

Comment: @sakhunzai i am facing one problem. the default advanced result functionality not working. if i give anything it returns all the records.

Comment: check the advance search query, make sure query criteria is properly added.

Answer (score 2):

```
'columns'=>array(
      array(
            'name'=>'columnName',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none;'),
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none;'),
            'filterHtmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none;'),
      ),
...
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation to you code, what it actually does?