# Yii CGridView customizing column head sort icons and row links

Tags: php, yii

I am dealing with the CGridView widget in Yii. I've customized most of it, but can't seem to customize the icons that appear when you click on the column headers to sort the data. (little arrows that point either up or down depending on the sort order) Also, the icons are completely gone after adding in the 'columns' option. A portion of the code in my view is below:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'pager' => array('cssFile' => '/css/myCss.css'),
'cssFile' => '/css/myCss.css',
'summaryText' => 'Showing {start} - {end} of {count} data rows.',
'htmlOptions' => array('id' => 'grid'),
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'value' => '$data->name',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'value' => '$data->description',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'date',
        'value' => '$data->date',
    ),
),
));
?>
```

Yii's documentation isn't clear at all on this and there doesn't seem to be anyone (that I could find) that also has this issue.

->Also, a related question:
How would I make each row an anchor link? I need each row to be a link to view the details about the clicked row. I know that cgridview provides view, edit, and delete links at the end of the row if told to, but is it possible to get the entire row to be a single anchor link? I know how to do this manually in html, but don't know how to do this inside cgridview.

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954292/hiding-columns-in-yii-cgridview/9954720 for clicking the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the icon in the header of the table, you will need to override styles for classes (`.grid-view table.items th a.desc` and `.grid-view table.items th a.asc`). You can also disable visual styles for the table by specifying an option: `'cssFile'=>false` and set custom styles for grid. 
In order to make the entire string anchor link is likely you will need to insert into each cell of the table with the necessary link url. To do this, add the following description of an array of strings:

```
'columns'=>array(
    ...
    array(         
       'name'=>'name',
       'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->name, "#myAnchor")',
       'type'=>'html'
    ),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what version of Yii you're working on, but let's try this code

```
<?php

'columns' => array(
array(
    ...
    'type' => 'html',
    'value'=>'CHtml::tag("a",array("class"=>"your-icon-class", "href"=>"#"))',
),
```